# Concatenating Quotation marks Around SQL Results to use in another Query using R

Tags: r

I have two queries: First one gets a list of IDs that are character type and then I want to use those IDs in another Query.

```
library(RODBC)

connection<- odbcConnect(dsn=production; db=production, uid='user1', pwd='p@ssw0rd')

IDs_of_Events<-sqlQuery(connection,
        "SELECT eventid
        FROM   ngh_events
        WHERE  event_period = 2"
        )
Count_Attendes<-sqlQuery(connection,
      paste("SELECT  eventid, COUNT(attendee_ID)
             FROM  paid_events
             WHERE eventid IN (", IDs_of_Events , ")
             GROUP BY eventid", sep="")
           )
```

The problem is I am unable to concatenate the list of eventids from the first query result to have a "EventID" ,  "EventID", "EVENTID"

Answer (score 0):

You have to collapse `IDs_Of_Events` into a single string using `paste`:

```
paste0("SELECT  eventid, COUNT(attendee_ID)
         FROM  paid_events
         WHERE eventid IN ('", paste(IDs_of_Events,collapse = "','") , "')
         GROUP BY eventid")
```

Note that I added the opening and closing single quotes in the other pieces. If you do this a lot, it's worth writing a wrapper for `paste` that does this stuff for you.